# Javascript function to FadeIn and FadeOut html item - working solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML

```
<div id="notifyProductName">
```

Angualar JS

```
<a href="" ng-click="cart.addItem(product.name,product.price, 1);cart.ShowItem(product.name)">
```

JavaScript

```
cart.prototype.ShowItem = function (productName)
{

  document.getElementById("notifyProductName").innerHTML = productName";
  document.getElementById("notifyProductName").fadeOut(400);
 }
```

I want to display the productName in a html message box and then fade the message box out after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a 3 second `setTimeout()` function and use a CSS class with `transition` on `opacity` for the fade.

```js
cart.prototype.ShowItem = function (productName)
{
  var el = document.getElementById("notifyProductName");
  el.innerHTML = productName;
  el.classList.remove('fade');
  el.classList.add('show');
  var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    el.classList.add('fade');
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.notifyProductName {
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="notifyProductName" class="notifyProductName"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! this works well to notify the first Product Name .However, when I add the second product nothing is displayed(as I am displaying it in the same html tag).

Comment: Hi @Arun can you update your post with whatever you're doing with a second product and what you've tried?

Comment: Hi Michael, so I am trying to add the selected product to the cart and eventually display the product name that was added..I have updated the code above in my initial question.

Comment: @Arun sweet! np :)